# How to show bottom Navigation bar in all pages in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

I am new in Flutter. There are three pages in my App. And i have a bottom Navigation Bar with Two Pages. Now how can i show bottom Navigation in 3rd page that is not my bottom navigation bar.

Comment: you should add your 3rd page to bottom bar.

Comment: What is keeping you from doing it? What happens if you try?

Comment: I find this solution (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qj7jcuU2Z10&ab_channel=Kiibati)